# C# file/folder monitor

Tags: c#, monitor, filesystemwatcher

I already managed to see file and folder changes with the FileSystemWatcher.

My problem is that I can't make a difference between files and folder. It's possible that a file and a folder have the same path names.

For the delete event I even can't use a dirty workarround with testing File.Exists(path) or Directory.Exists(path) because the file/folder is already deleted when the method is called.

Maybe this object has the info I need but I didn't found it:

```
FileSystemEventArgs e
```

I only want to know if the changed item was a file or a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution which is clean and always works:

The standard setting of a watcher is for files and folders. This makes no sense in my eyes since I can't find out which type the changed object had.

It's possible to create two filewatchers. One for files and one for folders. Then you just have to change the default settings as follows:

```
// for file
fileSysWatchFile.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
// for folder
fileSysWatchDir.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
```

Comment: The only problem is that FSW uses ThreadPool, so if you are using multiple watchers then the order of events that you will process might not reflect reality. The only solution I've found so far is to either use Change Journals as mentioned by ho1, or to write your own FileSystemWatcher using [this](http://qualapps.blogspot.cz/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html) and [this](http://qualapps.blogspot.cz/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw_19.html). Just throwing it out there for anyone who will come over this thread in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's on a NTFS volume I think you could do what you need by looking at the [Change Journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Specifically the [FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364586%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) control code and looking at the [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258117%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the [USN_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365722%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to see if it's a `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`.

You can find a sample here (in C++, but could possibly translate to C# or otherwise maybe just write a small C++ dll to call from your app): [Walking a Buffer of Change Journal Records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365736%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could test whether it has the *Directory* [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx):

```
var attributes = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\somepath");
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
{
    // it's a directory
}
else
{
    // it's a file
}
```

Of course if it has already been deleted this won't work and you won't be able to tell the type.

Comment: are you sure that will work in the case the OP highlights where the file/directory is deleted?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think we posted at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve the type of the deleted item unless you had a list of path->type mappings before where you can look up the last type of the deleted item.

Comment: ???... so if I have a file=C:\name and a folder=C:\name, I can't find out which was changed?

Comment: You can't have a file and a directory with the same name in the same folder.

Comment: anyway if it's already deleted you even can't find out if it was a file or a directory